# python win32com outlook 2013 SendUsingAccount return exception

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

While working on a simple mail automation with python and win32com api, I had an issue with SendUsingAccount. It was ignored or, worse, generating an error when I upgraded from windows 7 to windows 10.

Here is my original code

```
import win32com.client

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
oacctouse = None
for oacc in o.Session.Accounts:
    if oacc.SmtpAddress == "sender@mail.com":
        oacctouse = oacc
        break
Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
if oacctouse:
    Msg.SendUsingAccount = oacctouse
if to:
    Msg.To = ";".join(to)
if cc:
    Msg.CC = ";".join(cc)
if bcc:
    Msg.BCC = ";".join(bcc)

Msg.HTMLBody = ""

Msg.Send()
```

Resulting in the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 560, in **setattr**
    self.*oleobj*.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
com_error: (-2147417851, '\x83T\x81[\x83o\x81[\x82\xc9\x82\xe6\x82\xc1\x82\xc4\x97\xe1\x8aO\x82\xaa\x95\xd4\x82\xb3\x82\xea\x82\xdc\x82\xb5\x82\xbd\x81B', None, None)

My system is in Japanese.

I will answer my issue below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, I found the solution to my problem by chance on [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7afc9e42-ca4f-491b-8c50-19556fb4e1cf/sendusingaccount-does-not-work-in-outlook-2010-possible-bug?forum=outlookdev) at the very bottom (most of it is for VBA but the last post solved the python issue).

Here is the working code

```
import win32com.client

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
oacctouse = None
for oacc in o.Session.Accounts:
    if oacc.SmtpAddress == "sender@mail.com":
        oacctouse = oacc
        break
Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
if oacctouse:
    Msg._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, oacctouse))  # Msg.SendUsingAccount = oacctouse

if to:
    Msg.To = ";".join(to)
if cc:
    Msg.CC = ";".join(cc)
if bcc:
    Msg.BCC = ";".join(bcc)

Msg.HTMLBody = ""

Msg.Send()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that win32 black magic. It seems to be the only way to set the SendUsingAccount value. (For your information, I use Outlook 2013, Windows 7, and my system is in French, but not Japanese).

Comment: Sender account is obvious, but what do the parameters of the `Invoke()` method mean? It works, but I cant find it in the docs anywhere

Answer (score 3):

For others not having luck seeing their secondary account name show up under the "for oacc in o.Session.Accounts:" loop: try using Msg.SentOnBehalfOfName = '2ndaryemail@mail.com' . This worked for me!