# Sending outlook email using win32com on python from a secondary mailbox account

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I'm having an issue [like this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cc25d70a-eb6d-4bca-bcae-33c05380e61e/outlook-macro-sentonbehalfofname?forum=outlookdev)

```
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        accounts = win32com.client.Dispatch("outlook.Application").Session.Accounts
        print(accounts[1])
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        mail.SentOnBehalfOfName  =  accounts[1]
        mail.SendUsingAccount  =  accounts[1]
        mail.To = to
        mail.Subject = 'Subject TEST'
        mail.HTMLBody = emailBody
        mail.display()
        mail.Send()
```

if I comment `mail.Send()` the window that shows up will show everything correctly but if I send it, i'll get reply `This message could not be sent. You do not have the permission to send the message on behalf of the specified user.` which is obviously not true since if instead of sending directly and choose the exact same email from the dropdown menu in From, and then click SEND, it will send the email with no issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with the help of [@Eugene Astafiev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74195997/10747598) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57826082/python-win32-client-sent-email-from-a-secondary-outlook-account-from-its-own-out) I fixed the issue like this:

```
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        for account in outlook.Session.Accounts:
            if account.DisplayName == "email@email.om":
                print(account)
                mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
                mail._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, account))
                mail.To = to
                mail.Subject = 'Vodafone Support'
                mail.HTMLBody = emailBody
                #mail.display()
                mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use these both properties at the same time in Outlook:

```
mail.SentOnBehalfOfName  =  accounts[1]
mail.SendUsingAccount  =  accounts[1]
```

The From field available in the Outlook UI corresponds to the [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property which returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. This option is available when you have multiple accounts configured in Outlook.

The [MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) property returns a string, not an `Account` instance, where a string indicates the display name for the intended sender of the mail message. Be aware, the permission should be given to be able to send on behalf of another person in Exchange.

So, if you have got multiple accounts configured in Outlook you may go with the following line of code:

```
mail.SendUsingAccount  =  accounts[1]
```

Comment: I have the Account I need to send with added, how can I get to it with ```mail.SendUsingAccount``` ?

Comment: Just set the following property to the account instance - `mail.SendUsingAccount  =  account`