# Define mailbox to which to save an email - win32client python

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I would like to save an email to the drafts folder of a shared mailbox using the win32 API for Outlook. I can save an email to my (default?) mailbox drafts folder using the below:

```
def TestEmailer(text, subject, recipient):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    mail.Save()

TestEmailer('hello world', 'test', 'recipient@gmail.com')
```

Thanks to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38876817/programmatically-send-outlook-email-from-shared-mailbox) I can see that the `SendUsingAccount()` method can be used to send from a defined mailbox. Is there an equivalent method for *saving* to the drafts folder of a defined mailbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select `Save ()` when you switch your account to send email, which will be saved in the draft box of the new account.

Code:

```
import win32com.client as win32

def send_mail():
    outlook_app = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

    # choose sender account
    send_account = None
    for account in outlook_app.Session.Accounts:
        if account.DisplayName == 'sender@hotmail.com':
            send_account = account
            break

    mail_item = outlook_app.CreateItem(0)   # 0: olMailItem

    # mail_item.SendUsingAccount = send_account not working
    # the following statement performs the function instead
    mail_item._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, send_account))

    mail_item.Recipients.Add('receipient@outlook.com')
    mail_item.Subject = 'Test sending using particular account'
    mail_item.BodyFormat = 2   # 2: Html format
    mail_item.HTMLBody = '''
        <H2>Hello, This is a test mail.</H2>
        Hello Guys. 
        '''

    mail_item.Save()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_mail()
```

Here's a bit of black magic here. Setting `mail_item.SendUsingAccount` directly won't work. The return value is none. Always send mail from the first email account. You need to call the method of `oleobj_.Invoke()`.

**Updated:**

Oleobj document: https://github.com/decalage2/oletools/wiki/oleobj

Similar case: [python win32com outlook 2013 SendUsingAccount return exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35908212/python-win32com-outlook-2013-sendusingaccount-return-exception)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For my reference, could you link documentation for the `mail_item._oleobj_.Invoke()` method, or provide a short description of the inputs?

Comment: nice. but how do I save email as draft from my 2nd outlook account? This picks my default/primary account. How do I choose the 2nd account as sender email address?

Comment: In the `outlook_app.Session.Accounts`, I see only account displayed.