# Python automated Outlook email: change sender or default reply-to address

Tags: python, email, winapi, outlook

I'm using code similar to [Steve Townsend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210102/steve-townsend)'s answer from this question: [Send Outlook Email Via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332577/send-outlook-email-via-python)
to send an email by running a python script. How can I edit the default reply-to address, so that when someone replies to the automated email it will get sent to a specific address? Alternatively, can I modify the address that the email is sent from? I tried to modify the Msg.SentOnBehalfOfName property but had no success with that. Note that the address is an alias so I can't log into the account in Outlook.

```
import win32com.client

def send_mail_via_com(text, subject, recipient, profilename="Outlook2003"):
    s = win32com.client.Dispatch("Mapi.Session")
    o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    s.Logon(profilename)

    Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
    Msg.To = recipient

    Msg.CC = "moreaddresses here"
    Msg.BCC = "address"

    Msg.Subject = subject
    Msg.Body = text

    attachment1 = "Path to attachment no. 1"
    attachment2 = "Path to attachment no. 2"
    Msg.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
    Msg.Attachments.Add(attachment2)

    Msg.Send()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following code to choose sender address and recipient address freely.

```
import win32com.client as win32

def send_mail():
    outlook_app = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

    # choose sender account
    send_account = None
    for account in outlook_app.Session.Accounts:
        if account.DisplayName == 'sender@hotmail.com':
            send_account = account
            break

    mail_item = outlook_app.CreateItem(0)   # 0: olMailItem

    # mail_item.SendUsingAccount = send_account not working
    # the following statement performs the function instead
    mail_item._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, send_account))

    mail_item.Recipients.Add('receipient@outlook.com')
    mail_item.Subject = 'Test sending using particular account'
    mail_item.BodyFormat = 2   # 2: Html format
    mail_item.HTMLBody = '''
        <H2>Hello, This is a test mail.</H2>
        Hello Guys. 
        '''

    mail_item.Send()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_mail()
```

If you are interesting, you can refer this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58602116/define-mailbox-to-which-to-save-an-email-win32client-python/58608560#58608560).

Comment: I can't log in to the account because it's an alias. Will this idea still work?

Comment: @kayk Is this account bound to your outlook email?If you need to change the default sender, you can set the default sender's address on outlook in advance, and then use it to send mail by default in Python.