# Python email create

Tags: python, email, outlook, pywin32, win32com

i can create with python outlook emails and send them. Im Using

Comment: What do you mean by `timestamp` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python automated Outlook email: change sender or default reply-to address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59618725/python-automated-outlook-email-change-sender-or-default-reply-to-address)

Comment: Of what possible use is setting a random sender, other than for sending spam?

Answer (score 0):

The [SenderEmailAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.senderemailaddress) property is read-only and set on received or sent emails, not composed ones.

The Outlook object model provides two main ways for sending emails from other accounts:

- The [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property which returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. In that case the other account should be configured in an Outlook profile as well.
- The [MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) property which returns or sets a string indicating the display name for the intended sender of the mail message. In that case you need to have all the required permissions to do that on behalf of another person. Valid for Exchange only.

Answer (score 0):

On a general note, no mail server (certainly not Exchange Server)  will let you spoof the sender name and address (unless you were given an explicit permisison) for the obvious security reasons.

You can send on behalf of another Exchange user (if you have the permission) by setting the `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property. You can also create secondary Exchange / POP3/SMTP / IMAP4/SMTP accounts in Outlook and send through these accounts by setting the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property to an `Account` object from the `Application.Session.Accounts` collection.